# In Qt5 QWidget::winEvent does not exist

Tags: windows, qt, qt5

I use `::winEvent()` method to listen to system level notifications on Windows. With Qt5, this method does not exist anymore; so my application is not receiving any system level messages about added/removed devices.

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that `QWidget::winEvent()` has been replaced with new(and improved) `QWidget::nativeEvent()` method.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#nativeEvent

New method has a different signature than the old method, but in my case I just needed to switch to a new method without changing the code inside of my overloaded method at all.

Also, there is a new parameter in the new method named "event_type" that can come in handy as well.

Comment: An update that **silently** breaks working code is hardly an improvement. The `event_type` is pretty useless as well. With the little documentation available it appears that it can only ever have a single value. What used to be a lean implementation (`winEvent`) has been overdesigned into a meaningless signature. For the sake of platform independence. Of a platform specific feature.

Answer (score 0):

### Example

Imagine you need to be Qt 4 compatible, and your Window has some transparent parts, which you need to be click-through:

Header:

```cpp
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H
#define MY_CLASS_H

#include <QtCore/QByteArray>
#include <QWidget>

class MyClass : public QWidget {
    typedef QWidget super;
public:

    // ...

protected:

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  if QT_VERSION_MAJOR >= 5
    bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
#  else
    bool winEvent(MSG *message, long *result) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
#  endif
#endif

private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(MyClass)
};

#endif // MY_CLASS_H
```

Source:

```cpp
#include "my-class.h"

#include <QPoint>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   include <Windows.h>
#   include <windowsx.h>
#endif


#if defined(_WIN32)
#  if QT_VERSION_MAJOR >= 5
bool MyClass::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *messageVoid, long *result)
{
    if (eventType == "windows_generic_MSG")
    {
        MSG *message = reinterpret_cast<MSG *>(messageVoid);

#  else

bool MyClass::winEvent(MSG *message, long *result)
{
    {
#  endif // QT_VERSION_MAJOR

        if (message->message == WM_NCHITTEST) {
            QPoint pos = this->mapFromGlobal(QPoint(GET_X_LPARAM(message->lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(message->lParam)));

            if ( ! contentsRect().contains(pos)) {
                *result = HTTRANSPARENT;
                return true; // Stops further processing.
            }
        }

    }
#  if QT_VERSION_MAJOR >= 5
    return super::nativeEvent(eventType, messageVoid, result);
#  else
    return super::winEvent(message, result);
#  endif // QT_VERSION_MAJOR 

}
#endif // _WIN32
```

**Note** that Qt5 defines `Q_OS_WIN` and Qt4 defines `Q_WS_WIN` hence above uses `_WIN32`.